# Newer JunOS Versions numbers

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, srx

What is the meaning of the new JunOS version numbers in the 12.1 line?

- 12.1X44
- 12.1X45
- 12.1X46

What does the XNN mean? How can I tell which one I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

X indicates that it is a aggressive feature train per [KB27144](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB27144) and [TSB16034](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=TSB16034). The NN is a normal incremental version number.

Answer (score 0):

NN in 12.1XNN means. Its a special branch version. The code has been specifically modified for a particular customer or for a particular fix. :)